# How to insert element into child node

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to insert an additional 'cluster' into an existing XML topology.
Original XML:

```
[xml]$XmlObj = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Topology>
<Cluster Fqdn="db001.local">
<ClusterId SiteId="1" Number="1"/>
<Machine Fqdn="db001.local" UpgradeDomain="db001.local"/>
</Cluster>
</Topology>'
```

All fine. Now I want to add one more cluster:

```
[xml]$NewCluster = '<Cluster Fqdn="sp001.local">
<ClusterId SiteId="1" Number="1"/>
<Machine Fqdn="sp001.local" UpgradeDomain="sp001.local"/>
</Cluster>'
```

I have tried:

```
$XmlObj.Topology.Cluster.AppendChild($NewCluster.Cluster)
```

Returns the error. `"The node to be inserted is from a different document context."`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you can't just append a child node directly from another document.

First, you'll have to import it into your target document context:

```
$ImportedCluster = $XmlObj.ImportNode($NewCluster.Cluster, $true)
```

and now we can append it! I assume you meant to append the new `Cluster` node to the `Topology` child nodes, not the existing `Cluster` node:

```
$XmlObj.Topology.AppendChild($ImportedCluster)
```

Answer (score 3):

What `AppendChild()` does, essentially: It changes the `ParentNode` property of an XML node. And that can only succeed if both parent and child exist within the same document.

You can [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode?view=netframework-4.7.2) foreign nodes into the current document. This creates a clone, which then belongs to the new document, which can be attached to a new parent without issue.

```
$newClusterClone = $XmlObj.ImportNode($NewCluster.Cluster, $true)
Topology.Cluster.AppendChild($newClusterClone)
```